# PHP: unlink a file within register_shutdown_function (via anonymus closure) failes (windows)

Tags: php, function, shutdown, unlink

The scenario:

```
$value = "some PHP code";
$tmpFile = tempnam(realpath('file.test'), 'php');

file_put_contents($tmpFile, $value, LOCK_EX);

$process = function() use($tmpFile)
{
    //unlink('some previous failed unlink in register shutdown funciton on same file works here');
    ob_start();
    register_shutdown_function(function() use($tmpFile) {if(file_exists($tmpFile) && is_writeable($tmpFile)) {unlink($tmpFile);} exit;});
    include_once($tmpFile);
    unlink($tmpFile); //always works
    return ob_get_clean();
};

$value = $process();
```

The register_shutdown_function is there to clean up the tmp files, if include_once() failes with php errors. But when it is called because e.g. of a parse error in $value, the delete failes with a Permission denied error. When no error occures unlink works. It also works when trying to unlink a stale file that previously was not deleted within the shutdown function.

example error output:

```
Parse error: syntax error, .... on line 3
```

register_shutdown_function is called then and outputs

```
Warning: unlink(*****): Permission denied in **** on line 38
```

Only tested on windows so far.

Comment: It's possible that a) the file you're attempting to unlink is still in use (open file handles?) or b) that the `register_shutdown_function` is in a state where it can't remove the file (due to the shutdown process). Also looks like you need to use absolute paths in `register_shutdown_function` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#59300( if that helps

Comment: The parse error is because you are missing a `)` at the end of `register_shutdown_function(function() use($tmpFile`

Comment: @msfoster: Sorry, this is not the exact source code - this error occured in this post only.

Comment: @Tom: I use absolute paths only. I also assumed that it could have to do with the state of the shutdown process, but did not find anything in this regard on php.net. A temporary solution was the use of exec() (must check if available at the hoster...) to force a new process.